# iPad 2 back-facing camera field of view

Tags: ios, camera, augmented-reality, ipad-2, projection-matrix

I want to render virtual content over the camera image from the back-facing camera of the iPad 2. To achieve this, OpenGL ES is used to transform the content into the correct screen coordinates.

```
projectionMatrix =
    GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(FOV), 
                              16.0f / 9.0f, 0.05f, 5.0f);
```

The problem is the field of view parameter.

There were several posts about iPhone or the iPad 1; however, I couldn't find one yet for iPad 2.

What is the field of view of the iPad 2 in landscape 16:9 HD mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog will probably help you:

http://hunter.pairsite.com/blogs/20110317/

In particular,

> Using some basic trigonometry, this allowed me to determine that 4:3 stills taken with the iPad 2 back camera have an approximate 34.1 degree vertical field of view and an approximate 44.5 degree horizontal field of view. This equates roughly to a hypothetical 43mm focal length lens on a 35mm camera.

Comment: So, for 16:9 I can just go with 34.1 degrees / 960 * 1280?